# ExtJs 3.0 - Date range in the toolbar menu

Tags: extjs, extjs3

Is it possible to show date fields (I need date range) in the toolbar menu (button with context menu)?
**Note: Extjs 3.0**

So it will looks like this:

[image: context menu with date fields]

Edit:

I tried to add form with date fields:

```
items: [{
    text: 'Filter',
    iconCls: 'tracker-tb-filter',
    ref: '../trackerFilterBtn',
    menu: {
        items: [
            ... 

            '<b class="menu-title">Show:</b>',
            {
                text: 'All',
                checked: true,
                group: 'group-tracker-range',
                name: 'tracker-filter-range',
                value: 'all',
                handler: toolbar.filterTrackRecords.createDelegate(this)
            }, {
                xtype: 'form',
                text: 'From/To',
                group: 'group-tracker-range',
                checked: false,
                name: 'tracker-filter-range',
                handler: toolbar.filterTrackRecords.createDelegate(this),
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'datefield'
                    }
                ]
            }

            ...

        ]
    }
}]
```

But fields were not showed at all:

[image: fields were not showed]

Comment: Yes, it is. I don't know what to say more at this point... What exactly are you asking. Did you face any problems while doing this? You may need add some code where you stuck.

Comment: So if that is possible - I wanna see working example :)

Comment: Nice try ;) SO is not for 'give me code'. I will help you if you stuck at some point but I will not write you your code.

Comment: For me this worked. I tested it with ExtJS3.4

Comment: Sorry for confusing - I'm using Extjs 3.0. It is not possible to update to the latest one, maybe if I'll know what to change directly in ext-all-debug.js...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I haven't found a way to realize what I need.

I tried ExtJs 3.4, but there were issues with keep menu opened when we select a date.
If somebody still will find a way - please write here.

---

So I did a trick - I generated an east panel with all required fields, it is showed when we click on the button in toolbar. And it looks in this way:

[image: Filter Panel]

Answer (score 0):

nice alternative solution. if you still need a solution without generate a panel, I found this trick work :
on parent menu we add 'beforehide' on listeners, it's just a single line function that return true value.
...
menu: {
    width: 300, padding: 10,
    listeners:{
        **beforehide: function(){
            return false;
        }**
    },
...

Comment: Hmm, in the question you can see that the issue is with the 'fields were not showed at all'. I think your idea will not fix this :)